# Issue in implementing shortcut keys in flex application

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to implement some short cut keys in my flex application. Some of them are Cntrl+Z, Cntrl+Y, Cntrl+O, Cntrl+S etc  .  But it gets overlapped with the shortcuts with the browser.  Is there any way to handle the short key combination in flex applications?

Thanks in advance
Manoj

Comment: You should use jquery/javascript over the <object>/<embed> tags , to prevent the default action from taking place.So, the key stroke will reach the flash object, but will not reach the browser.http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Javascript-Disable-Mouse-click-Browser_t825.html tells you about disabline right clicks, similarly you can disable keydowns/keyup events too.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is your friend to make it work in Internet Explorer browser... http://www.mehtanirav.com/how-to-stop-keyboard-event-propagation-flex-javascript/